# Is it possible to see how the stats of an Area51 proposal have changed during beta?

Tags: support, area-51

I'm currently actively involved in a site proposal that is in public beta. Viewing the stats on Area51 for this site isn't really promising. Now I would like to have a look how this stats have changed during the public beta phase, i.e. if for example the average question per day is increasing or decreasing or constant.

Is there any possibility to see that?

Comment: I believe only appointed moderators can see that information?

Comment: I agree, it seems strange to me that in the Definition and Commitment phases we have graphs of the key metrics, but not in Beta. I'd also like to see graphs for the beta sites I'm involved in!

Answer (score 4):

Moderators have access to that information, although they should not share very specific data in public. But if you ask on your meta or in chat, they might give you the rough trend of the data, but probably not any specific graph.